# How i convert login-config in web.xml to java class?

Tags: java, servlets

How i convert login-config in web.xml to java class?

I have standart login config in web.xml

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>UserDatabase</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/login.xhtml?error=true</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>
```

and login page which is rendered in xhtml

```
<form name="login" id="login" action="/c/j_security_check" method="post">

            <table class="auth">
                <tr>
                    <th><label for="username">#{loginMsg.login}</label></th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="j_username" />

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="j_password" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" onclick="return auth();" class="login">
                            #{loginMsg.enter}
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;" onclick="return checkForm();"/>
        </form>
```

I need just perform login-config in java class. Help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to JSR-315 **[Servlet 3.0 Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1509624646_5d5973a35c04be089fd5b7e5bd8b49fc)** : Ch13.6.3 (pg132),

The **only** way to configure **form**-based authentication is by using **deployment** **descriptor** (web.xml or web-**fragment**.xml).